# How to set SSL properly in Apache Tomacat? HTTP works fine

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, centos7, tomcat8

HTTPS works fine in nginx front-end but login refused.HTTP also works fine.
This is the Error shown in chrome console
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ().
I have created abc.jks file.
My server.xml configuration looks like this

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->

<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/etc/ssl/certs/abc.jks" keystorePass="MYPASSWORD"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>

<!-- Define a SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the NIO implementation that requires the JSSE
     style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
     OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in theAPR/native
     documentation -->

  <!-- <Connector
    port="8443"protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
   -->    `
```

Comment: does your application host a favicon.ico file ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell The application has various icon but not favicon.ico

Comment: favicon is requested by default by the browser, it should be logged as a 404 if this file is not available, and not as a 500. Is there anything in your application which handles all requests ? Maybe just put an empty favicon.